# how to reduce line space for <pre>

Tags: html, css, pre

## **reproducible code**

Hello, I used the following code in markdown

```
<pre><span style="color:blue">Text            = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Selected Text='Sooo SAD'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Sentiment = 'negative'</span></pre> 
<pre>tokens          =</pre>
<pre>input_ids       = [0, 2430, 98, 3036, 5074, 939, 40, 2649, 47, 259, 11, 15610, 1597, 2977, 16506, 2, 1, 1...1]</pre>
<pre>attention_masks = [1, 1,    1,  1,    1,    1,   1,  1,    1,  1,   1,  1,     1,    1,    1,     1, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>start_tokens    = [0, 0,    1,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>end_tokens      = [0, 0,    0,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>Edit Text       = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!' (len=46), Edit Seletected Text='Sooo SAD' (len=8)</pre>
<pre>char            = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0...0] (len=46, num_1=9)</pre>
<pre>offset          = [(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 9), (9, 11), (11, 16), (16, 21), (21, 25), (25, 30), (30, 33), (33, 37), (37, 41), (41, 43), (43, 46)]</pre>
```

## **undesired effect**

and generate the following effect
[image]

But the too wide line space makes the effect is kind of ugly. Do you know how to redue the line space?

## **Tried method**

I tried this method

```
<pre style='display:inline'>tokens          =</pre> <br>
<pre>input_ids       = [0, 2430, 98, 3036, 5074, 939, 40, 2649, 47, 259, 11, 15610, 1597, 2977, 16506, 2, 1, 1...1]</pre>
```

But it only works for one line, if I want to apply to other lines such as this

```
<pre style='display:inline'>tokens          =</pre> <br>
<pre style='display:inline'>input_ids       = [0, 2430, 98, 3036, 5074, 939, 40, 2649, 47, 259, 11, 15610, 1597, 2977, 16506, 2, 1, 1...1]</pre> <br>
<pre>attention_masks = [1, 1,    1,  1,    1,    1,   1,  1,    1,  1,   1,  1,     1,    1,    1,     1, 0, 0...0]</pre>
```

it would cover part of line content
[image]

## **Question**

How to reduce the line space? Thank you

Comment: Why not use one `<pre>` for all lines?

Comment: a `<pre>` tag has `margin: 1em 0px;` by default, setting a custom margin will fix your issue.

Comment: Good idea!! I will try @Aziz

Comment: That explains!! Thanks! @RamondeVries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use css `display` and `line-height` properties on the `pre` elements and adjust the line-height you want.

```css
pre {
   display: inline;
   line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<pre><span style="color:blue">Text            = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Selected Text='Sooo SAD'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Sentiment = 'negative'</span></pre> 
<pre>tokens          =</pre>
<pre>input_ids       = [0, 2430, 98, 3036, 5074, 939, 40, 2649, 47, 259, 11, 15610, 1597, 2977, 16506, 2, 1, 1...1]</pre>
<pre>attention_masks = [1, 1,    1,  1,    1,    1,   1,  1,    1,  1,   1,  1,     1,    1,    1,     1, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>start_tokens    = [0, 0,    1,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>end_tokens      = [0, 0,    0,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>Edit Text       = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!' (len=46), Edit Seletected Text='Sooo SAD' (len=8)</pre>
<pre>char            = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0...0] (len=46, num_1=9)</pre>
<pre>offset          = [(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 9), (9, 11), (11, 16), (16, 21), (21, 25), (25, 30), (30, 33), (33, 37), (37, 41), (41, 43), (43, 46)]</pre>
```

Or reset the default margin.

Comment: Thank you!! This works for me`<pre style='display:inline;line-height:2em;'>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `margin: 0` (or any other value)  for `pre` in CSS:

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre><span style="color:blue">Text            = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Selected Text='Sooo SAD'</span>,   <span style="color:blue">Sentiment = 'negative'</span></pre>
<pre>tokens          =</pre>
<pre>input_ids       = [0, 2430, 98, 3036, 5074, 939, 40, 2649, 47, 259, 11, 15610, 1597, 2977, 16506, 2, 1, 1...1]</pre>
<pre>attention_masks = [1, 1,    1,  1,    1,    1,   1,  1,    1,  1,   1,  1,     1,    1,    1,     1, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>start_tokens    = [0, 0,    1,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>end_tokens      = [0, 0,    0,  0,    1,    0,   0,  0,    0,  0,   0,  0,     0,    0,    0,     0, 0, 0...0]</pre>
<pre>Edit Text       = ' Sooo SAD I will miss you here in San Diego!!!' (len=46), Edit Seletected Text='Sooo SAD' (len=8)</pre>
<pre>char            = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0...0] (len=46, num_1=9)</pre>
<pre>offset          = [(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 9), (9, 11), (11, 16), (16, 21), (21, 25), (25, 30), (30, 33), (33, 37), (37, 41), (41, 43), (43, 46)]</pre>
```